# Identify this plant with a pink flower spike?

Tags: identification, bromeliads

What's this plant? I'm in the Caribbean

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I presume you mean the pink flower - it is a Pink Quill (*[Tillandsia cyanea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tillandsia_cyanea)*), a native of Ecuador. It likes to be kept warm and moist but not wet. Accustomed to living up in the branches of trees in tropical forest. There is also a red flower variety.